# VS Code ruby-rubocode increase Metrics/MethodLength check

Tags: visual-studio-code, rubocop

Rubocode (in VS Code's ruby-rubocode extension) insists that no method should be longer than 10 lines:

```
Metrics/MethodLength: Method has too many lines. [11/10] (convention:Metrics/MethodLength)
```

I think that this is a bit severe, and would like to change it to 20.

Is it possible to edit this value via VS Code's `settings.json`?

**Update**
B)  Is it also possible to increase the `Metrics/LineLength` from 80 to 120?

```
Metrics/LineLength: Line is too long. [108/80] (convention:Metrics/LineLength)
```

Answer (score 5):

You can edit rubocop `config/default.yml` to do what you are looking for.

Look at the Metrics section and change `Metrics/LineLength` and `Metrics/MethodLength` values.

If you want to change these settings for your current project only then create `.rubocop.yml` file in the required project directory:

```
Metrics/LineLength:
  Max: 120
Metrics/MethodLength:
  Max: 20
```